# Autoreconf stops with "non-POSIX variable name"

Tags: makefile, posix, autoreconf

I created a Makefile.in where I read the content out of a file and pass it to CFLAGS. Calling ./configure ... the Makefile will be generated an all works well.

```
Makefile.in: 
... 
MY_REVISION_FILE=my-revision.txt 
MY_REVISION=$(shell cat $(top_srcdir)/$(MY_REVISION_FILE)) 
AM_CFLAGS = -I$(EXTRAS_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(top_srcdir) -DMY_REVISION=$(MY_REVISION) 
...
```

The problem arises once I moved the Makefile.in code into Makefile.am to allow the auto generation of  Makefile.in. There calling autoreconf -i --force stops with the following error:

```
server/Makefile.am:9: cat $(top_srcdir: non-POSIX variable name 
server/Makefile.am:9: (probably a GNU make extension) 
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

This problem hunts me now since quite some time. I searched everywhere but did not find anything that could help me finding a solution for that. In short, the only thing I need is a way to get an uninterpreted text such as "$(shell cat $(top_srcdir)/$(MY_REVISION_FILE))" copied from Makefile.am to Makefile.in

Any idea?

Thanks, 
Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says, the problem is you're using a GNUism in your `Makefile.am`, when it's only meant to contain portable Makefile code.

Either rewrite your code so it's portable (you should use `AM_CPPFLAGS` because you're passing flags to the preprocessor, not the compiler):

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(EXTRAS_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(top_srcdir) -DMY_REVISION=`cat $(top_srcdir)/$(MY_REVISION_FILE)`
```

If you don't want to invoke `cat` on every compile, you could find the value in `configure.ac` and either `AC_SUBST` it into `Makefile` or `AC_DEFINE` it so it goes into `config.h`.

Or if you want to be non-portable (ಠ_ಠ), you can take `-Werror` out of your `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` or `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS`, or add `-Wno-portability`.

Answer (score 1):

After long testing back and forth I decided to use AC_SUBST. 
My solution might not be the cleanest but it works for me.

In configure.ac I added the following line
    AC_SUBST([DOLLAR_SIGN],[$])

In the Makefile.am I changed my previous line into
    MY_REVISION=@DOLLAR_SIGN@(shell cat $(SRC_DIR)/$(MY_REVISION_FILE))

And it works.
Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this code online somewhere? I could suggest something less hacky if so.

Comment: Actually I removed the AC_SUBST hack and replaced it with -Wno-portability. It;s just a nicer way of doing it. But hey, its nice to know how AC_SUBST works ;-)