# Build shared library,written in c++, by using gnu autotools on Mac/OS X?

Tags: macos, autotools, automake

I want to port a c++ program I wrote from linux to mac, which including shared library projects. I used gnu automake to do the build things. Now I have many issues stop me from using automake to build my program on mac.

What effort I have made:

1. Installed xcode 5.1.1 and its command line tools(looks like it not helpful, it doesn't have automake)
2. Installed automake libtool manually by homebrew
3. Followed a typical automake workflow: autoscan, autoconf, aclocal, automake, configure, make... then a bunch of errors appeared.
4. Searched in google heaps, no complete tutorial about this particular task was found.

Here is some issues I can describe:

The first thing is to let the shared lib to be built. I found the libtool name is 'glibtool' on mac, so I need to use glibtool instead of libtool, I put this: 
    LIBTOOL=glibtool
in Makefile.am do the trick. And I also need to check OS let it only do this for Darwin system. The following should work in shell but seems not working for Makefile.am:

```
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
else
    UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
        LIBTOOL = glibtool
    endif
endif
```

It will lead to "error:else without if". Not sure how to achieve this?

The left is the generated Makefile basically not working. Typing 'make':

> cd ../.. && /bin/sh /Users/viewpl/lab/rdwtwdb-git-code/rdwtwdb/missing automake-1.14 --gnu plugin/dictcn/Makefile
>   source='../../rwd_util.cpp' object='../../rwd_util.lo' libtool=yes \
>       DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../../depcomp \
>       glibtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include/ -iquote../../include/ -iquote../../   -g -O2 -c -o ../../rwd_util.lo ../../rwd_util.cpp
>   glibtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2  -rpath /usr/local/bin/plugin/  -o libdictcn.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/rwd dictcn.lo ../../rwd_util.lo  -liconv -lltdl -lz -lxml2 -lreadline -lpthread -lportaudio -ldl -lcurl 
>   glibtool: link: `../../rwd_util.lo' is not a valid libtool object

Missing .lo files, looks like it doesn't compile .cpp into .lo. I tried to work around by running the g++ statement manually, it can help to generate .lo.
I end up by this error:

> glibtool: link: c++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libdictcn.0.dylib  .libs/dictcn.o ../../.libs/rwd_util.o   -liconv -lltdl -lz -lxml2 -lreadline -lpthread -lportaudio -ldl -lcurl  -O2   -install_name  /usr/local/bin/plugin/ /usr/local/lib/rwd/libdictcn.0.dylib -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.0 -Wl,-single_module
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/rwd/libdictcn.0.dylib'

I spent much time searching on internet but doesn't help much. 
[The documentation of Apple's official site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/intro/intro.html) is not very helpful to solving gnu autotools usage problems on mac.

The complete source code can be found by this:

```
git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/rdwtwdb/gitcode rdwtwdb-gitcode
```

I am using OS X Mavericks v10.9.2. Thanks for any advice.

---

**Add more information to help asking why I cannot build `.lo` when typing `make` under the library folder, Makefile has been generated by using glibtool**

When typing `make` under the library fold, it complains `.lo` files are missing:

```
source='dictcn.cpp' object='dictcn.lo' libtool=yes \
    DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../../depcomp \
    /bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include/ -iquote../../include/ -iquote../../   -g -O2 -c -o dictcn.lo dictcn.cpp
source='../../rwd_util.cpp' object='../../rwd_util.lo' libtool=yes \
    DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../../depcomp \
    /bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include/ -iquote../../include/ -iquote../../   -g -O2 -c -o ../../rwd_util.lo ../../rwd_util.cpp
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2  -rpath /usr/local/bin/plugin/  -o libdictcn.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/rwd dictcn.lo ../../rwd_util.lo  -liconv -lltdl -lz -lxml2 -lreadline -lpthread -lportaudio -ldl -lcurl 
libtool: link: `dictcn.lo' is not a valid libtool object
make: *** [libdictcn.la] Error 1
```

But the way to build `.lo` has been given in the output. Why it doesn't use it to build `.lo`?
I looked into Makefile itself, found the rule to build `.lo` is this:

```
.cpp.lo:
    $(AM_V_CXX)source='$<' object='$@' libtool=yes \
    DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CXXDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
    $(AM_V_CXX_no)$(LTCXXCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<
```

---

**Final target is to build `.la` file successfully**

Despite of the previous issue, I can build `.lo` manually. It's not too bad if I can half-automake the project. But when I trying to build the last `.la`, this missing `.dylib` error stop me from doing that:

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2  -rpath /usr/local/bin/plugin/  -o libdictcn.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/rwd dictcn.lo ../../rwd_util.lo  -liconv -lltdl -lz -lxml2 -lreadline -lpthread -lportaudio -ldl -lcurl 
libtool: link: warning: ignoring multiple `-rpath's for a libtool library
libtool: link: g++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libdictcn.0.dylib  .libs/dictcn.o ../../.libs/rwd_util.o   -liconv -lltdl -lz -lxml2 -lreadline -lpthread -lportaudio -ldl -lcurl  -O2   -install_name  /usr/local/bin/plugin/ /usr/local/lib/rwd/libdictcn.0.dylib -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1.0 -Wl,-single_module
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/rwd/libdictcn.0.dylib'
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but try `ifneq` instead of `ifeq` followed directly by `else`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `ifeq`...`endif` makefile syntax won't work in `automake` because of indentation.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403224/425738) shows a more reliable way of handling `uname` cases in `configure.ac`.

I'm not that familiar with homebrew.  Does homebrew also call `libtool` and `glibtool` and `libtoolize` and `glibtoolize` like the native OS X GNU Libtool?

At any rate, setting up `LIBTOOL` in `Makefile.am` is far too late.  It needs to be handled by `autoreconf` which invokes `libtoolize` which writes `libtool.m4` (the template for `libtool` written by `configure`).  Something like this could work if that's the case:

```
LIBTOOLIZE=glibtoolize autoreconf -fvi
```

Whenever I had to build on OS X with the GNU Build System, I'd install all the autotools.  The OS X autotools were invariably ancient and unusable on OS X.  The homebrew libtools package might be OK, but again I don't have any experience with them, so I really can't say for certain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used homebrew to install new autotools. I am not familiar with libtoolize/glibtoolize.
Anyway I tried adding 'LIBTOOL=glibtool' and 'LIBTOOLIZE=glibtoolize' in configure.ac, looks like the generated Make still not able to output .lo 
'libtool: link: `dictcn.lo' is not a valid libtool object'

Comment: Adding `LIBTOOLIZE` and `LIBTOOL` to `configure.ac` won't fix it, because it's too late there also.  You might want to check out the documentation for `autoreconf`.  And double check what the homebrew libtool scripts are called.

Comment: I think I am using the right libtool now, because I checked the generated 'libtool' file at the root of project, it's version 2.4.2, the same as result of `$glibtool --version`. 
Do you have an idea of why Makefile in my library giving correct command-line to build .lo, but not running to build .lo when I typing `make`?